# wrap text around picture on another picture

Tags: text-wrap

I have a small picture on top of a larger photo.

I am trying to wrap text around the small picture.

To keep type on top of the large photo, I need to select "ignore text wrap" which does not allow me to wrap type rung the small photo on top.

How can wrap text around the small photo?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi j porter, what program are you trying to do this in?

Comment: You'll really need to specify which software you use (as AndrewH suggested). There's many ways to do this and you might get even more answers if you edit your question to add the specific software you're using for this!

Answer (score 2):

**For InDesign**

1) Place larger photo on document. Make sure it has "No Text Wrap"

[image: No Text Wrap]

2) Place your text over the large photo.

3) Place another Rectangle frame tool and paste into or do file place to place your small image on the document. Put this over the text layer. When have the small image selected, select "Wrap around bounding box".

[image: Wrap around bounding box]

Result

[image: wrap text on photo result]